# How to see Check-out date in Visual SourceSafe History

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

How do I view when projects/folders/files were checked out in Visual SourceSafe history?

Currently to see the history I do the following:-

1. Right-click on project in the
2. Select "Show History" in context menu.
3. Check "Recursive" and "Include file histories" in Project History Options Dialog
4. Click Ok

I can see when files are "checked in", "Added", "Deleted", but no entries for the Check-outs.

Comment: What do you want that for? On the face of it, it's not that useful a piece of information in the context of history.

Comment: Fair argument @TonyHopkinson, unfortunately I cannot tell that to the audit guys who what to establish exactly when I check out code.

Comment: Long time since I used source safe. Don't remember, seeing check out date, maybe you could show best endeavors and trap the event and log it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509341(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on a file->Properties->Check Out Status. You should be able to find the check-out date info there.